# How to add an FTP-only user in command line on Ubuntu set up with ispCP Omega?

Tags: ftp

I'm actually a programmer and I'm currently developing a web application where one of it's demands is to create an ftp folder and user when a new user registers with the web app. So a newly registered user can upload stuff in his/her own ftp folder. Those uploaded files get read by the web app, etc.

For the obvious security reasons I don't want to create shell users but ftp users only.

I came across the info to simply create the user with `useradd` and setting its shell to `/bin/false`, what ispCP actually does when you create an ftp user in the admin interface. But what I simply couldn't find out is where ispCP actually stores its FTP users. If I do a simple `cat /etc/passwd` I don't see the users that I can see in the ispCP admin panel, except for the common user with the name `ftp`.

So I was wondering if there's a certain place I need to look into to see the users that were created over the ispCP admin panel. I need to integrate my app into the system, so I though of mirroring the process that ispCP does. I unfortunately can't ditch it because other things are running on the server...

The system specs are:

- ispCP 1.0.5 OMEGA
- ProFTPD Version 1.3.2

PS: I couldn't tag it with ispcp due to my low reputation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proftpd can be configured to look at a [database for accounts](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/SQL.html).  Do that, and then build yourself an app that inserts records into the database.